# writing this algorithm with do while loop

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, do-while

I am trying to solve [USACO trainings](http://ace.delos.com/usacogate), The "Your Ride Is Here" problem can be solved with this algorithm:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int Calculated(char * calc_me);

int main() {
    char * comet_name = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 7);
    if (comet_name == NULL) {return 0;}
    char * group_name = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 7);
    if (group_name == NULL) {free(comet_name); return 0;}

cout << "Enter the name of the comet: ";
cin >> comet_name;
cout << "Enter the name of the group: ";
cin >> group_name;

if ((Calculated(comet_name) % 47) == (Calculated(group_name) % 47)) {
   cout << "GO";
}
else {
     cout << "STAY";
}
 free (group_name);
 free (comet_name);
 return 0;
}

int Calculated (char * calc_me) {
    int i;
    int total = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if (calc_me[i] == '0') {break;}
        total *= calc_me[i] - 64;
    }
    getch();
    return total;

}
```

Im trying to change the for loop with do-while loop, Here is my code,so I replaced it with do-while, it doesn't work, can anyone mention me which part I am doing it wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int Calculated(char * calc_me);

int main() {
    char * comet_name = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 7);
    if (comet_name == NULL) {return 0;}
    char * group_name = (char*)calloc(sizeof(char), 7);
    if (group_name == NULL) {free(comet_name); return 0;}

    cout << "Enter the name of the comet: ";
    cin >> comet_name;
    cout << "Enter the name of the group: ";
    cin >> group_name;

    if ((Calculated(comet_name) % 47) == (Calculated(group_name) % 47)) {
       cout << "GO";
    }
    else {
         cout << "STAY";
    }
     free (group_name);
     free (comet_name);
     return 0;
}

int Calculated (char * calc_me) {
    int i;
    int total = 0;
    do
    {
        total *= calc_me[i] - 64;

        i += 1;

    }while(i < 7);
    getch();
    return total;

}
```

this is the sample input :
COMETQ
HVNGAT

```
GO
```

ABSTAR
USACO

```
STAY
```

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: could you provide sample input and expected output!!

Comment: @Robin question updated

Comment: You know doing a bit more work and thinking about things is recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (calc_me[i] == '0') {break;}
```

should read

```
if (calc_me[i] == '\0') {break;}
```

and that condition is missing from your do-while version, along with the initialisation of `i`.

But the main problem is that you changed the initial value of `total` from 1 to 0:

```
 int total = 0;
```

so this line

```
 total *= calc_me[i] - 64;
```

keeps multiplying zero by the next value.

Answer (score 2):

AH!! found it!!

You have initialized `total to 0`. So, every multiplication becomes 0 hence your functions always returns 0.

Initialize your total variable to `1` and it should work.

Comment: I did that in my code before

Answer (score 0):

In the code snippet below, you need to initialize `i` with a value before you can do `i += 1`. You do it in the for statement in the for-loop, similarly you need to do it for the do-while loop as well.

```
int i = 0;  // initialize to 0
int total = 0;
do
{
    total *= calc_me[i] - 64;

    i += 1;

}while(i < 7);
```

Comment: That's it? It doesn't work? No other information? How am I supposed to help you with just "It doesn't work". Is it a runtime or a compilation error? What's the compiler saying?

Comment: You forgot the "if( calc_me[i] == '0' ) break;"

Comment: In that case, it's an error in your logic. Either try what JCash suggests, or step through your code in a debugger and inspect the variables.

Comment: lets say we don't need if statement for know, I've tried your solution before, xbonez